# Внешняя и локальная сеть-попытки связи

Tags: сеть

Имеется локальная сеть из нескольких машин и одной корпоративной машины, которая подключена как к локальной сети, так и к корпоративной (стоит сетевая плата с 2-мя портами).

Корпоративная машина соединена с одной из локальной машин по протоколу Телнет. 
Необходимо удалённо через корпоративную машину( ip адрес-известен) узнать ip адрес локальной машины и каким то способом запустить протокол телнет и по нему связаться с локальной машиной.

Все указанные машины на Виндовс.

Comment: А что такое "связаны по протоколу телнет"? У меня слишком много вариантов, что это может быть

Comment: TELNET (сокр. от англ. teletype network) — сетевой протокол для реализации текстового терминального интерфейса по сети. Это значит, что к локальной машине есть доступ по TELNET, но этот доступ возможен только через корпоративную машину.

Comment: ок, я понял. классический ответ программиста - абсолютно правильный и абсолютно бессмысленный.

Видимо, лучшим способом в Вашем случае будет спросить ответственного человека.  

У Вас машины уже связаны (то есть соединены), поэтому не нужно пытаться. Может просто нужно этот терминал найти?

или все таки "они могут быть соединены" и нужно "соединиться"?

Comment: Смотрите  корпоративная машина уже соединена с локальной машиной по TELNET.
Необходимо удалённо из этой корпоративной сети узнать ip адрес локальной машины у которой установлено соединение по TELNET с корпоративной машиной (ip адрес этой машины известен).

Comment: я думаю, я знаю что Вам нужно. Если соединение уже есть, то в этом терминале нужно просто дать команду status, она покажет имя и прочие данные

Comment: она работать не будет это специализированная консоль связь с которой осуществляется по TELNET. но прежде нужно узнать ip-адрес локальной машины подключенной к корпоративной машине. на корпор.машине набираю команду netstat -aon и я это соединение по TELNET вижу вместе с портом. 
Но как удаленно из этой корпоративной сети определить ip адрес  локальной машины подключенной по TELNET к копаративной машины (ее ip адрес известен).
по типу такой команды :  netstat -aon   ip-адрес-корпаративной-машины

Comment: проброс портов  это не в ту степь???

Comment: если у Вас "специализированная консоль", тогда только в документации к этой специализированной консоли.

Comment: Как узнать ip-адрес локальной машины подключенной к корпоративной машине. Может через cmd есть такие команды??

Comment: а netstat уже нельзя использовать?

Comment: я вбиваю команду  удаленно с другой машины из этой же корпоративной сети типа:  netstat -aon  ip-адрес-корпоративной-машины(подключ. по TELNET), но выдает не то.